# several tableviews in one view

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I am trying to make a view that contains several tableViews in it - basically a week calendar view that each day is a tableView that shows the events of that day.

In the storyboard I'v added to the view a tableView and tried to connect it in two different ways in the viewDidLoad:

```
DaysTableViewController * tvc = [[DaysTableViewController alloc]  initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.dayView.delegate = tvc;
self.dayView.dataSource = tvc;
```

or:

```
DaysTableViewController * tvc = [[DaysTableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
self.dayView = tvc.tableView;
```

when dayView is my IBOutlet property for the tableView in the storyboard.
but it crash in both ways, and I dont know where it crash in the code.

I know the DaysTableViewController itself works fine, because when I push it in a NavigationController it works.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'v found the problem.
it was a simple memory management problem, I mad the Object that was the dataBase in the ViewDidLoad and didn't have a strong property for it, and just got released...
thanks everyone for the answers.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use TableViews inside a ViewController, not a TableViewController.  A TVC can only have one tableview.

Comment: That's sort of not true.  UITableViewControllers just conform to the delegate and datasource automatically.  As for multiple tables, it's hard, but not impossible.

Comment: @CodaFi, I think what he means is that if you are using multiple tableviews at once, then you should put them into a UIViewController and not a UITableViewController, which is something I agree with.

Comment: I am using a viewController, not a tableViewController. but I want the delegate and the dataSource to be in a different object. I tried to make an object that implement <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>, and put it instead of DaysTableViewController, but it still crushed. when I put the same code in the main (week) ViewController it works fine.